# Matching a string against values of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, matching

i'm trying to make a kind of log in system whereas i'd have a string that would be got from user input and i want to check if that input is in a specific array…

What i got so far:

```
var name = $(".input").value();
var options = ["option_one", "option_two", "three"];
$(".submit").click(function() {

for(i=0; i < options.lenght; i++){
    if(options[i] == name){
        alert("true")
    }else{
        alert("false")
        }
}


});
```

Can anyone help me out?

EDIT: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/angus/pen/PWgBxa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplier method - use `.includes()` function.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEVBgN

```js
var name = $(".input").val();
var options = ["option_one", "option_two", "three"];

console.log(options.includes(name) ? 'valid!' : 'invalid!');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='input' value='three'>
```

Comment: always alerts false :C

Comment: @Miguel Check once again. Type `three` and hit click button.

Comment: @Miguel Exactly. The variables were filled immediately when page was loaded. So the value of input was `undefined` all the time.

Comment: @Miguel My pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) like this:

```
if(options.indexOf(name) != -1){
    alert("valid")
}else{
    alert("false");
}
```

`indexOf` will return an index (>=0) from the array where the element is found, -1 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use the javscript `Array.prototype.some()` function:

```
var name = $(".input").value();
var options = ["option_one", "option_two", "three"];
if(options.some(el){
  return el == name;
}){
  alert("valid")
}else{
  alert("false");
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some